# How can I export my Outlook 2010 contacts and calendar to the iPhone without having iTunes on the PC?

Tags: iphone, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2010, export, contacts

I've upgraded to Windows 7 x64 and iTunes is giving me all sorts of problems (hanging, crashing) so I've decided to run it from my Mac mini.

However, I need to get my Outlook 2010 contacts and calender onto the iPhone. I figured that I might be able to export them to the OSX address book and calendar, but this doesn't appear to be the simple task I thought it would be.

Anyone know how to transfer contacts and calendar from Outlook 2010 to the standard OSX contacts and calendar apps?

Answer (score 2):

Use Outlook 2010 to sync with Google Calender and Google Contacts, and then use [Google sync to sync the Contacts and Calenders OTA](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740).

Answer (score 0):

You can sync your contacts between Outlook 2010 and OSX contacts app (and more) using the free webapp [Soocial](http://www.soocial.com).  It says the Outlook support is beta, but I've been using it on Outlook 2010 without any trouble for a while now, and Soocial for quite a while longer.

[GCCALDaemon](http://gcaldaemon.sourceforge.net/index.html) might do what you want for the calender side. It looks more complicated to set up, but very powerful.